# Mysql joining 2 tables in same query. Inner join or Left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 2 tables at once, the problem is that im getting an empty set with the following query.

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name, b.id, c.id from a
inner join b on a.id = b.a_id
inner join c on a.id = c.a_id
inner join d on a.d_id = d.id
```

My guess is that this is happening because both B and C tables not always have matching records with the A table.

My example DB looks like this:

```
A Table:
|id|name |d_id|
|1 |one  |1   |
|2 |two  |1   |
|3 |three|2   |

B Table:
|id|a_id|
|1 |1   |

C Table:
|id|a_id|
|1 |2   |

D Table:
|id|name|
|1 |hey |
|2 |ho  |
```

What i expect in my resultset will looks like this:

```
Result-set:
|a.id|a.name|d.name|b.id|c.id
|1   |one   |hey   |1   |NULL
|2   |two   |hey   |NULL|2
|3   |three |ho    |NULL|NULL
```

[image: What i want to select]

(Excluded from my sketch the D table because i think i will have no problem with this). Also tried with left join with no luck

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did a `left join` not work?

Comment: That needs left join.

Comment: You don't say what the problem in using the left joins is, but if you have any where conditions it could be this: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: Alright, i was wrong explaining my question and the LEFT JOIN solves the problem in the above example. In my actual situation i was doing a SUM function so i had to use the GROUP BY statement. For all who read this question the LEFT JOIN approach will accomplish what i explain in this question; but if you need to use any aggregation function dont miss the GROUP BY as i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say, if B and C not always have matches, you need to left join those (and those only).

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, d.name, b.id, c.id
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b on (a.id = b.a_id)
    LEFT JOIN c on (a.id = c.a_id)
    JOIN d on (a.d_id = d.id);
```

Here A and D must always match, while matching records from B and C may be there or else be NULL.

(Remember that *all* values from B and C will be NULL in nonmatched rows, in case you add a `WHERE` clause or something like that).

## Test (click [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48686/1/0) for a fiddle)

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE a
    -> ( id integer, name varchar(20), d_id integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'one', 1), (2, 'two', 1), (3, 'three', 2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE TABLE b ( id integer, a_id integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE c ( id integer, a_id integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE d ( id integer, name varchar(20) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 'hey' ), (2, 'ho');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT a.id, a.name, d.name, b.id, c.id
    -> FROM a
    ->     LEFT JOIN b on (a.id = b.a_id)
    ->     LEFT JOIN c on (a.id = c.a_id)
    ->     JOIN d on (a.d_id = d.id);
+------+-------+------+------+------+
| id   | name  | name | id   | id   |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
|    1 | one   | hey  |    1 | NULL |
|    2 | two   | hey  | NULL |    1 |
|    3 | three | ho   | NULL | NULL |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
```

(Note, in your example c.id is 2, but in your data there's actually a 1).

Comment: Yes, actually your explanation made me realize that i was using an aggregation function, so i had to use a GROUP By and now its working, i was missing that 'little' detail in my question. Thanks ! EDIT: Also +1 for "Here A and D must always match"

Answer (score 2):

Use LEFT JOIN:

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name, b.id, c.id from a
inner join b on a.id = b.a_id
LEFT join c on a.id = c.a_id
LEFT join d on a.d_id = d.id
```

Comment: OP also should use left join between table a and b. Because he says: "because both B and C tables not always"

Answer (score 2):

The query misses the left joins between tables:

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name, b.id, c.id from a
left join b on a.id = b.a_id
left join c on a.id = c.a_id
left join d on a.d_id = d.id
```